# Changing the onClick area when adding an event

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there anyway to change what a user clicks on to add an event? Right now the entire day is clickable. This becomes an issue when the user needs to put focus back on that window, requiring a mouse click. If they click on the calendar, which takes up most of the page, then they launch the "Add Event" function.

Is there a way to have a Plus sign (+), or whatever symbol in each day that when clicked, launches the "Add Event" function? Or... Is there a way to have a button across the top that said, "Add Event"?

Answer (score 0):

What I did as a work around is to customize the daySegHtml function in the fullcalendar sources. Hope this help.
gf